# Floor lamp w/five adjustable lamps

Tags: lighting

Calls for 60W max incandescent bulbs.  Salesman sold me A19 Dimmable LED Gen Purpose 60W replacement/uses only 6.5W.  Is this safe? This is not a dimmable light.

Comment: Next time  don't pay for dimmable  bulbs. They are more expensive and your fixture is not dimmable.

Comment: @JACK, I had considered mentioning that in my answer, but one local retailer carries only dimmable and I considered that may also be the OP's situation.

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable, honestly.  Imagine if the conversation was "Don't pay for THWN wire when you only need THHN".  (these days the price difference is so small they just make it all double-listed).

Answer (score 4):

The light bulbs suggested by the salesman will operate at full intensity, as you've indicated that the fixture does not include dimming features. At full intensity and 6.5 watts per bulb, you are well under the safe maximum noted in your first line.

You are safe by a substantial factor.